# typescript вывести изображения из массива

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

Получаю от бэка массив изображений (в base64) которые не знаю как разместить на страничке. Помогите, пжлста. Если в массиве 1 элемент, то всё OK, если больше - изображения не отображаются.

```
@property({
    type: Object
}) qrCode = [];


render() {
    console.log(this.qrCode)
    return html `
        <div id="qr-img">
            <img src="${this.qrCode}"
                 style="display: block; margin: auto" onclick="printDiv()"/>
        </div>
    `}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сработало только без `.join`

```
@property({
  type: Object
}) qrCode = [];


render() {
    return html `
        <div id="qr-img">
            ${this.qrCode.map(x => html `
                <img src="${x}"
                     style="display: block; margin: auto" onclick="printDiv()"/>
            `)}
        </div>
    `}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас же написано, что qrCode это массив. А вы его как строку просто выводить пытаетесь.

```
@property({
    type: Object
}) qrCode = [];
```

Когда приходит 1 элемент это тоже массив, или просто строка?
Если массив:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.qrCode)
    const images = this.qrCode.map(i => `
        <div id="qr-img">
            <img src="${i}"
                 style="display: block; margin: auto" onclick="printDiv()"/>
        </div>`
    );
    return html images.join()}
```

Если когда 1 элемент то приходить просто строка, то необходимо выполнить проверку

```
Array.isArray(this.qrCode)
```

Если тру, то вариант как я показал выше, если фолс - фаш вариант

Answer (score 0):

Можно с помощью метода `map()` создать новый массив строк, которые будут содержать значения из массива `qrCode`, а затем с помощью метода `join()` объединить получившийся массив в одну строку, её и возвращать в методе `render()`

```js
const qrCode = ["src1", "src2", "src3"];

const html = qrCode
              .map(
                (src) => `
<div id="qr-img">
  <img src="${src}" style="display: block; margin: auto" onclick="printDiv()"/>
</div>`
              )
              .join("");

console.log(html);
```